# Get Sum from each row form-field

Tags: javascript, sum

I trying to calculate some rows (input fields) but it seams to hard for me :(.
The html code i have looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="Field_Price_1" id="Field_Price_1" value="20.55" type="text">
    <input name="Field_Amount_1" id="Field_Amount_1" type="text">
    <input name="Field_SubTotal_1" id="Field_SubTotal_1" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="Field_Price_2" id="Field_Price_2" value="17.55" type="text">
    <input name="Field_Amount_2" id="Field_Amount_2" type="text">
    <input name="Field_SubTotal_2" id="Field_SubTotal_2" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="Field_Price_3" id="Field_Price_3" value="94.20" type="text">
    <input name="Field_Amount_3" id="Field_Amount_3" type="text">
    <input name="Field_SubTotal_3" id="Field_SubTotal_3" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="Field_Price_4" id="Field_Price_4" value="12.10" type="text">
    <input name="Field_Amount_4" id="Field_Amount_4" type="text">
    <input name="Field_SubTotal_4" id="Field_SubTotal_4" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="Field_Price_5" id="Field_Price_5" value="7.45" type="text">
    <input name="Field_Amount_5" id="Field_Amount_5" type="text">
    <input name="Field_SubTotal_5" id="Field_SubTotal_5" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

So i would put the sum from all input fields "Field_Price_" in the following span by triggering "keyup" from each Field_Amount_".

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><span id="PrintSum">0.00</span></td>
</tr>
```

The following i tried:

```
var total = 0;
var Price = $('input[id^=Field_Price_]').val();
   $.each($(Price), function(){
      total += $(this).val();
   });
$('#PrintSum').text(total);
```

So that won't work.
Do any know what is the problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean don't work? error ? Have you check error console?

Comment: Thats the point, because no error there!

Comment: Give us sample input and output

Comment: How you mean that sample in- and output? Url?

Comment: the value for each input and the output

Comment: Damn i forgot a input field in my html (i updated now). So the Subtotal have to be calculated .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be parse the input value to an float.

```
var total = 0;
var Price = $('input[id^=Field_Price_]').val();
   $.each($(Price), function(){
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
   });
$('#PrintSum').text(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/5qVvF/), an example not using jquery, but you could modify to do testing there

```
var prices = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=Field_Price]"),
    ammounts = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=Field_Amount]"),
    subTotals = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=Field_SubTotal]"),
    printSum = document.getElementById("PrintSum");

function sumIt() {
    var total = 0;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(prices, function (price, index) {
        var subTotal = (parseFloat(price.value) || 0) * (parseFloat(ammounts[index].value) || 0);

        subTotals[index].value = subTotal.toFixed(2);
        total += subTotal;

    });

    printSum.textContent = total.toFixed(2);
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(prices, function (input) {
    input.addEventListener("keyup", sumIt, false);
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(ammounts, function (input) {
    input.addEventListener("keyup", sumIt, false);
});

sumIt();
```

Here is a jquery version of above, on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/WFJnK/)

```
var prices = $("input[id^=Field_Price_]"),
    amounts = $("input[id^=Field_Amount_]"),
    subTotals = $("input[id^=Field_SubTotal_]"),
    printSum = $("#PrintSum");

function sumIt() {
    var total = 0;

    prices.each(function(index, price) {
        var subTotal = (parseFloat(price.value) || 0) * (parseFloat(amounts.eq(index).val()) || 0);

        subTotals.eq(index).val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
        total += subTotal;
    });

    printSum.text(total.toFixed(2));
}

prices.on("keyup", sumIt);

amounts.on("keyup", sumIt);

sumIt();
```

<strike>I will modify my pure javascript version soon to show you how your further questioning can be achieved, without the need of including jquery</strike>.

It has now been updated so you can see how it works

And a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jq-vs-js-sum1) showing the construction performance of the two

Comment: that should work but it calculates allways the first input element of each row. si how that if the calculated input element has id like this "input[id^=Field_Total_]"?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/r5Xqp/1/)

```
var total = 0;
var Price = $('input[id^=Field_Price_]');
   $.each($(Price), function(){
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
   });
$('#PrintSum').text(total);
```

Comment: check bug fixed from int to float

Answer (score 0):

use this javascript

```
$(':input[id^="Field_Price_"]').keyup(function() {
    var total = 0;
    var $inputs = $(':input[id^="Field_Price_"]');
    $inputs.each(function (index)
         {
           total += parseFloat($(this).val());
         });
    alert(total);
    $('#PrintSum').text(total);  
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pradkumar_n/PLzT4/6/)

Comment: Sorry, but that returns me allways 150!

Comment: Sorry dude, it looks you have also to learn some jquery like me.. lol  But thank you anyway, I like how you would help me. Thanks again.

Comment: i have posted old jsFiddle link, check this now http://jsfiddle.net/pradkumar_n/PLzT4/6/

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

```
var $prices  = $('input[id^=Field_Price_]'),
    $amounts = $('input[id^=Field_Amount_]');

$prices.add($amounts).on('keyup', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $prices.each(function() {
        total += $(this).val() * $(this).next().val() || 0;
    });
    $('#PrintSum').text(total.toFixed(2));
})
.trigger('keyup');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UFSvF/

Here changing the price as well as an amount triggers total price recalculation.

Comment: Thats cool dude, but what if you have additional one inputfield more, eg. this: `<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="Field_Price_2" id="Field_Price_2" value="17.55" type="text">
    <input name="Field_Amount_2" id="Field_Amount_2" type="text">
    <input name="Field_SubTotal_2" id="Field_SubTotal_2" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>`